# Is there any limited access to MathSciNet for retired mathematics faculty?

Tags: mathscinet

I am a retired mathematics professor and AMS member continuing to do research and publish papers.

Unfortunately, my former university (39 years) allows library access only to Emeritus Professors so I have no access to JSTOR or MathSciNet, putting me at somewhat of a disadvantage.

Needless to say, living on a retirement pension puts individual subscriptions beyond my means.

Have other academic retirees found workarounds to similar situations?

Comment: Many journal articles can be accessed through Sci-Hub.

Comment: I know that it's not much help, but is it possible to request emeritus status?  I don't know if it can be granted retroactively, but my impression was that most universities are willing to offer the status without too much hassle.

Comment: @LSpice Unfortunately my application disappeared into a black hole of plausible deniability.

Comment: To clarify, is this only an issue off-campus, or both on- and off-campus?  I think that at many universities you can access their online subscriptions if you are connected to the network on campus (sometimes, guest access suffices).  Also, can your old department help even if your university won't?

Comment: @Kimball The specific issue in the case of my institution is losing one's faculty username/password upon retirement. So it is both an on & off campus issue.

Comment: @AlexeyUstinov Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[Zbmath](https://www.zbmath.org/) is now completely open, and hence it is a free alternative to Mathscinet.

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware of this site.

Comment: Happy to help. Note, though, that the major problem is accessing papers, and Zbmath won't solve it.

Comment: And if my paper were to be reviewed somewhere, I would have no way of knowing.

Comment: @Glorfindel Please do not make edits just to enforce your personal style preferences in other people's writing. This is, in my view, akin to changing American to British spelling, which is frowned upon on the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni it's not my personal style, AFAIK it's [the official way of writing it](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/help/about.html?version=2)...

Comment: @Glorfindel No, that's *their* preferred way to write it. Other people, including professional copy-editors, disagree: http://www.theslot.com/webnames.html .

Comment: Whatever, you seem to be in a [six to one minority](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1368856) here. But I'll try to remember your preference.

Comment: @Glorfindel Please don't remember it just as 'my preference'; it's the normal capitalization rule in standard English grammar. :)

Comment: Now I'm curious how you write MathOverflow ...

Comment: Or McDonald's, for that matter.

Comment: I have checked on data.se: I have written Mathoverflow 3 times and MathOverflow once here (but I usually abbreviate it to MO). About McDonald's, that's a good question; I think traditional English grammar uses a capital D; but then again this spelling is very old and wasn't invented as a marketing gimmick by the burger company, unlike most logo stylizations.

Comment: (And, to reciprocate, I am curious why you 'fixed' MathSciNet but not zbMATH.)

Comment: Because I knew (a bit) about MathSciNet, but not about zbMATH ...